# Perplexity is too large

Tags: r, pca

I am trying to run [{Rtsne}](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rtsne/Rtsne.pdf). On `pca` dataset prepared by using `dudi.pca` from [{ade4}](https://pbil.univ-lyon1.fr/ade4/ade4-html/dudi.pca.html).

For pca calculation I selected 40 components while specifying parameters for `dudi.pca`:

```
pca = dudi.pca(counts(sce_normalized), scannf=FALSE, nf=40)
```

{Rtsne} gives me an error: “perplexity is too large”, how could it be fixed?

The code I am trying to run is below:

```
name_of_file <- "dudi_pca.rds"
path_to_file <- paste0("/scratch/nv4e/scRNA-
seq/normalization/new_datasets/",
                   name_of_file, sep="")
dudi_pca <- readRDS(path_to_file)

# run Rtsne with default parameters
rtsne_out <- Rtsne(as.matrix(dudi_pca), pca=FALSE)
```

Comment: What are the dimensions of `dudi_pca`?

Comment: The dimensions are `20 000 x 40`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using `dudi_pca` incorrectly. The supplied parameter to `as.matrix()` should have been `dudi_pca$li`:

```
rtsne_out <- Rtsne(as.matrix(dudi_pca$li), pca=FALSE)
```